# SOQL for Approval History

Tags: soql, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to create this in an LWC and can't put together the right SOQL to grab all the data:
[image: Approval History]

`SELECT CreatedDate, StepStatus, OriginalActor.Name, Actor.Name, Comments from ProcessInstanceStep where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :accountId`

gets me just about everything except the first Step Name column.

I see there's a `ProcessNodeName` field in `ProcessInstanceNode` that seems to have what I'm after but I don't know how to join the two object together. I'm not sure if this is where I should be looking, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some inspiration from [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205496/soql-to-pull-out-approval-history-records), I found that the `ProcessInstanceHistory` object can be accessed via the `StepsAndWorkItems` relationship on `ProcessInstance`.

I did need to assume the first step in the process is named "Approval Request Submitted" by default since that entry seems to have no `ProcessNode.Name`, however.

My Apex method ended up looking like this:

```
public List<ProcessInstanceHistory> getApprovalHistoryByAccountId(Id account) {
    ProcessInstance pi = [
        SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, ProcessNode.Name, CreatedDate,
                     StepStatus, OriginalActor.Name, Actor.Name, Comments
                     FROM StepsAndWorkitems
                     ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                    ) 
        FROM ProcessInstance
        WHERE TargetObjectId = :accountId
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ];
    return pi.StepsAndWorkitems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub-query on `ProcessInstance` to find the related `Steps` should do the trick.

```
SELECT Status,
    (
    SELECT CreatedDate, StepStatus, OriginalActor.Name, Actor.Name, Comments
    FROM Steps
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    )
FROM ProcessInstance
WHERE TargetObjectId = :accountId
```

---

UPDATE

As per comment below a modification to the query in the original attempt to answer.

```
SELECT Id, LastActor.Name,
    (SELECT Id, Actor.Name, StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps),
    (SELECT Id, ProcessNodeName from Nodes)
FROM ProcessInstance
WHERE TargetObjectId = :accountId
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

- **Step Name**: Taken as `ProcessNodeName` from a child object of `ProcessInstance` called `Nodes`
- **Date**: Taken as `CreatedDate` of `ProcessInstance`
- **Status**: Taken as `StepStatus` from a child object of `ProcessInstance` called `Steps`
- **Assigned To**: Taken as `Actor.Name` from a child object of `ProcessInstance` called `Steps`
- **Actual Approver**: Taken as `LastActor.Name` of `ProcessInstance`
- **Comments**: Taken as `Comments` from a child object of `ProcessInstance` called `Steps`

Comment: It appears this is essentially the same as the query in my question except it uses a subquery on ```ProcessInstance```. I'm looking for the step name in particular.

Comment: @d2013 try the updated code. They don't make the relationships easy between the objects holding those fancy related list line items!!

Comment: It's still not clear which ```Node``` belongs to which ```Step``` in this case since there are no IDs linking them together. I may be able to approximate it by ordering each subquery by ```CreatedDate``` perhaps and using the array indices. I agree that this object structure seems unnecessarily complicated, especially since I can't use ```ProcessInstanceHistory``` which is what the screenshot in my question seems to use.